# Doctrine simple array / array transform to postgres int array?

Tags: postgresql, doctrine-orm

I use Doctrine 2.6.3 with Symfony 4.3.1 and Postgres 10

Unfortunately when I specify a simple_array or array column type, the Doctrine just simple create that column as TEXT, but why? Postgres supports int arrays too.

```
     @ORM\Column(type="simple_array", nullable=true)
```

I want to store some enum values here: [1, 2, 3, 4] and thats all, integers.

How can I force Doctrine to creaet int_array type for the column instead of text?

Answer (score 2):

Both `array` and `simple_array` default to [`text`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.9/reference/types.html#array-types):

> This type will always be mapped to the database vendor's text type
>   internally as there is no way of storing a PHP array representation
>   natively in the database.

If you want to leverage native types giving up on portability, you can give this [doctrine dbal extension](https://packagist.org/packages/opsway/doctrine-dbal-postgresql) a try.